# Are there any disadvantages to Gradle Prefab AARs?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, prefab

I'm primarily an Android Java developer, but I have a need for libyuv.  I created a module and have it building under CMake.  I read about prefab, and for developers like me this is a game changer.  As such, I want to share my module as a prefab.  I ran into an issue where the ANDROID_STL had to be set to "c++_shared" as opposed to the default (static).  So I started reading some more about it.  This statement got me thinking prefab might not be the best approach.  "This [static runtime] allows the linker to inline and prune as much unused code as possible, leading to the most optimized and smallest application possible."  https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#static_runtimes

To me it sounds like the linker performs shrinking, like R8, but only for static.  So, the question is it there a performance or size penalty for using prefabs in this way?

My repo (WIP):  https://github.com/dburckh/libyuv-aar

Note: In this particular case, I think I can safely use "ANDROID_STL=none" for my libyuv library as it doesn't use C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems in your question aren't actually unique to prefab. See the following docs:

- https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#one_stl_per_app
- https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/middleware-vendors#using_the_stl

If you distribute a shared library that uses libc++_shared, your users must also use libc++_shared. That's no different if you use prefab or distribute in another fashion; prefab is just the only tool that proactively defends you against these mistakes.

Now, where prefab does come into this is the options it gives you to work around those constraints:

1. Distribute a shared library with a dependency on libc++_shared. Any app that consumes your library is forbidden from using libc++_static.
2. Distribute a shared library with no libc++ dependency (either the library is C and you use `ANDROID_STL=none`, or because you've carefully followed the advice in the middleware doc). Your consumers are free to use either libc++_shared or libc++_static (or neither), but they must still ship the entire dependency (dead-code-elimination and LTO cannot operate on a shared library dependency).
3. Distribute a static library. This offers the most flexibility to your consumers. Since your library has not yet been linked the decision between libc++_shared and libc++_static has not been made yet, and the consumer can use either. This also allows the consumer to use LTO on your library, inlining and eliminating dead code as appropriate. The only downside is that if the consumer's app contains multiple shared libraries which each need to consume your library, they cannot use a static library (that would violate ODR).

**The best thing you can do as a package author is do both 3 and either 1 or 2.** 3 is the best option for consumers that can safely use the static library, whereas 1 and 2 are good enough for those that can't.

Note that to include both in the same package, you should rename the static version as `libyuv_static` or whatever so that the static and shared variants have unique names.

One last thing, because AGP doesn't have enough context to know how your AAR will be used, you do need to intervene to prevent it from shipping libc++ in the wrong directory: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/eb8c57aaf8e4e8da8debfe7a6f44149630ac775e/prefab/prefab-publishing/mylibrary/build.gradle#L55-L62.

> Note: In this particular case, I think I can safely use "ANDROID_STL=none" for my libyuv library as it doesn't use C++.

Correct. That's the right answer for this specific case (and all C-only libraries, which are quite common).

Comment: Thank you for the wonderfully detailed answer!  I read some more on LTO and static vs shared libraries.  It leads me to the question, "Since my intended user base is NDK developers, why would I even bother with a shared library for this use case?"  FYI:  There is another excellent libyuv library that exposes libyuv to Java (https://github.com/crow-misia/libyuv-android)

Comment: I can't say I completely understand all the nuances, but I believe the issue requiring the exclude of the .so files is fixed.  I've looked at the AAR's generated for both 3 & 2 and neither have redundant .so files.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168777344

Comment: "Since my intended user base is NDK developers, why would I even bother with a shared library for this use case?" See 3 above. ODR.

Comment: The most recent comment you see on that bug is me. I'm trying to get that tracked down, but what I'm turning up so far is that the bug is that only a subset of the problem is fixed, and it was accidentally closed as part of that. The problem still exists afaict, it just won't cause build failures in the case where the duplicates are genuine bitwise identical duplicates, which isn't a problematic case anyway. This is still a real bug whenever it could actually cause runtime problems.

Comment: I've built a static release and published it to the github repo.  You can see it here: https://github.com/dburckh/libyuv-aar/packages.  I've dog fooded it in my camera app and it appears to be working properly.  The AAR looks good to me, but if you see an issue let me know.  If someone asks for a shared version, I'll try to figure out how to build both.  :)